# How to change datepicker date format like dd/mm/yyyy in ngbdatepicker

Tags: typescript, angular8, ngb-datepicker

I am using ng-boostrap for datepicker:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api
But i do not know how to change date format like dd/mm/yyyy. Now it is displaying yyyy/mm/dd but i want like dd/mm/yyyy.Please help anyone.

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wpn3h-ahcq4x?file=src/app/datepicker-popup.html

```
  <div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
         name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This should help: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2072

Comment: @jdaz: How to implement that in my code? Can you update my stackblitz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using ng-bootstrap's `NgbDateISOParserFormatter` [as a guide](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/ngb-date-parser-formatter.ts), create a custom formatter in `datepicker-popup.ts`. The code below is (IMO) a little more straightforward than the original and doesn't rely on importing `util.ts`:

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function padNumber(value: number | null) {
  if (!isNaN(value) && value !== null) {
    return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class NgbDateCustomParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct | null {
    if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split('/');

      let dateObj: NgbDateStruct = { day: <any>null, month: <any>null, year: <any>null }
      const dateLabels = Object.keys(dateObj);

      dateParts.forEach((datePart, idx) => {
        dateObj[dateLabels[idx]] = parseInt(datePart, 10) || <any>null;
      });
      return dateObj;
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct | null): string {
    return date ?
        `${padNumber(date.day)}/${padNumber(date.month)}/${date.year || ''}` :
        '';
  }
}
```

Then import `NgbDateCustomParserFormatter` and set the provider in `@NgModule` in `datepicker-popup.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
    {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateCustomParserFormatter}
   ]
```

I've forked your StackBlitz and added this functionality [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wpn3h-bhou8a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.ts).

Comment: Date is coming like this:  024/06/2020  Please see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wpn3h-dbvhfx?file=src/app/datepicker-popup.ts

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I had it returning a two-digit year. To change to a four-digit year, don't change `padNumber` to `slice(-4)`. Instead, just remove the call to `padNumber` on `date.year` in the formatted return string. Fixed above and in my StackBlitz link.

Comment: Again it is coming in alert (26/6/2020) .If month is single digit zero should be add before that. How to do it? see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wpn3h-mwfgxl?file=src/app/datepicker-popup.ts

Comment: The widget returns an `NgbDate` object, so if you want a particular string formatting you have to format it again. If you make the `NgbDateCustomParserFormatter`  `format()` method static you can reuse it like I've done here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wpn3h-ulkpmc